# Augmented Reality-PC

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I recently saw the virtual mirror concept on you tube, I tried it out and researched about it. It seems that the creators have used augmented reality so that people can see the output on their screens. On researching I found out that we identify a pattern on which a 3D image is superimposed.

Question 1:How are they able to superimpose the jewellery and track the face of the person without identifying any pattern?

I also tried to check various libraries that I can use to make a program similar to the one they show. Seems to me that a lot of people are using Android phones and iPhones and making apps that use augmented reality.

Question 2:Is there any way that I can use c++ and try to make a program that uses augmented reality?

Oh, and the most important thing, the link to the application is provided below:

http://www.boutiqueaccessories.com.au/virtual-mirror/w1/i1001664/

Do try it out. Its a good experience. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to actually try the live demo, but the linked video suggests that they either use some simplified pattern recognition (get the person's outline), or they simply track you based on the initial image (with your position/texture being determined by the outline being shown.

Following the video, it's easy to see that there's no real/advanced AR behind this. The images are simply overlayed or hidden (e.g. in case it's missing track of one ear due to you looking to the side) and they're not transformed (no perspective or resizing happening). They definitely seem to track the head (or features like ears, neck, etc.). depending on your background and surroundings that's actually a rather trivial task.

Question 2: Sure! There are lots of premade toolsets out there, but you could as well use some general image processing library such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to do the math. Augmented reality usually uses some kind of pattern (e.g. a card or page with a known pattern) to determine the correct position and transformation for the contents to be added to the image. There are also approaches using the device's orientation and perspective changes in camera images to determine depth/position (I really like [this demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZiSK7OMANw)).

Comment: You saw the youtube video? And I have made the face recognition program using OpenCV, the problem is that it does not track the ears with the face, it tracks only the face. I tried ear tracking also but the problem is that the outline is not so accurate.

  Can you please expand your answer to question 1 when you say that no advanced AR is used?
How do the earrings manage to turn when the girl turns her head?

Comment: Check the video around 1:15 - the ear is rather "jumpy" so I guess they're just looking for that part of skin color "sticking out".

Comment: Ok, so I track my ear and try to find the position of the earlobe so that I can make something similar to the ear ring trial thingy that they have shown? That seems do-able. But how about the hand or the neck? How do I track them? If I use OpenCV for upper body tracking it only gives me the outline in the form of a rectangle/ellipse/circle etc. etc.

Comment: It's not more than that. You know the position of the head or body, so you have to use further analysis to find other things (e.g. the ear). You know where the head is, so look for skinny parts sticking out: below you'll find the neck, on the left/right you might find ears. You can also try to use image segmentation and then try to track the segments only. I don't think they ever detect the hand - the "gesture controls" simply detect moving in the corners I'd assume.

Comment: You seem to be correct on the ear and neck tracking. So if I want that necklace trial program, I calculate the position of the face and that calculate the position of the neck w.r.t the face? Now the only thing that remains is the body and its really hard to track the body as the haar features are not so well defined as the face. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'd assume some default proportions and then let the user move a bit to the left/right and use the motion to approximate the real width. As an alternative approach, you could do it the way the Android Camera app cuts out video backgrounds: Take a picture of the background, then compare this to the user image to "see" the user (i.e. parts being different).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13654/discussion-between-prakhar-mohan-and-mario)